# Create a toggle button that changes text when layer is on and when layers is off

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, layer, togglebutton

I have created this code that makes a toggle button that can switch layers on and off in a leaflet. Switching layers on and off works fine. But I also want the text in the toggle button to change. When a layer is on the leaflet map it has to say: "Layer on" and when there is no layer on the map it needs to say: "Layer off". I tried implementing

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
    return text == 'Layer off';
});
```

and

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
     return text == 'Layer on';
});
```

But it returned the text "false" in the button. This is the function I used:

```
$("#layerControl").click(function(event) {
  layerClicked = window[event.target.value];
  if (map.hasLayer(layerClicked)) {
    map.removeLayer(layerClicked);
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text == 'Layer off';
    });
  } else {
    map.addLayer(layerClicked);
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
      return text == 'Layer on';
    });
  }
});
```

**Edit**

I'm trying to fire the function again after a change is made in a selectlist. This is the code I have at the moment but it's not working yet:

```
$('#slctListValue').change(function ()
{
        $("#layerControl").click(function( event ) {
                    layerClicked = window[event.target.value];
                        if (map.hasLayer(layerClicked)) {
                            map.removeLayer(layerClicked);
                            $(this).text('Layer Off');
                        }
                        else{
                            map.addLayer(layerClicked);
                            $(this).text('Layer On');
                        } ;

        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than returning a boolean value, I suggest returning a string value conditionally, based on the current text content.

Below, I'm using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to determine the new text.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#output').text(function(i, text) {
    return text == 'Layer off' ? 'Layer on' : 'Layer off';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<div id="output">Layer off</div>
```

---

### Edit:

However, looking at the spirit and intent of your code, I might just set the appropriate text based on whether the layer is showing. Two separate conditions may just complicate things and introduce unexpected behavior.

```js
$("#layerControl").click(function(event) {
  layerClicked = window[event.target.value];
  if (map.hasLayer(layerClicked)) {
    map.removeLayer(layerClicked);
    $(this).text('Layer Off');
  } else {
    map.addLayer(layerClicked);
    $(this).text('Layer On');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! I have unother question, If I want this function to be refreshed when `$("div")` is changed. Can I just put the code above within: `$("#theDiv").click(function( event ) { "The answer of you within here" };`?

Comment: You have `$("#layerControl").click(...)`. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: No I have a select list, and when the selection in the select list is changed I want the function to check again if there is something on the map.

Comment: Sounds possible, probably using a [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) listener on your select list. But I'm not sure exactly how you are detecting map layers. Can you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38085522/edit) to include a working example of what you've got so far?

Comment: I can't add a working example because I can't post my code because of some policy's I'm dealing with. But I posted an update of the code that isn't working yet, and I'm working on at the moment. But I think it's not working because now it only get's fired when #selectListValue is changed or am I wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing your HTML (and other relevant code). The code you added will bind a click handler to `#layerControl` every time the select list is changed; I don't think this is the functionality you want. You'll need to find a way to pass a selected layer (`layerClicked`) from your select list rather than from a click event.

Comment: Yeah I understand, srry I can't provide more code. But the thing now is that you'r answer worked great. But when a user for example selects a layer in the selectList, the button is on: "layer on" which is fine. And when the user clicks on the button again and the layer is off and the button says: "layer off" that's fine to. But if the user than makes a new selection in the selectList a layer get's displayed and the button is still on: "layer off" while it should be on "layer on".

Comment: Is it possible to show your select list? Does it contain values that are associated with the map layers?

Comment: The values in the select list are database table names. These values are used in a query that is being send to the database and eventually outputs the layer on the map.

Comment: The general idea is that your original `click` handler defines a variable called `layerClicked`. You use that value to check whether the layer is on the map. So, if you switch it to a `change` handler, that handler will also need to define a variable that pertains to a specific layer so that you can check whether it is on the map. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah oké, but where would you implement the change handler than?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this

```
text == 'Layer off'; // not-work!    
text = 'Layer off'; // work!
```

Comment: this makes no sense, why should you return a assignment of a variable?

Comment: the example is with his own code that he has, it's just remove one character '='